# Dynamically set Office 365 content add-in dimensions

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I would like to set the width and height of a content addin dynamically. I am aware that the initial width and height properties are set in the manifest. e.g.

```
 <RequestedWidth>340</RequestedWidth>
<RequestedHeight>720</RequestedHeight>
```

My problem is to dynamically set the dimensions at runtime. Is this possible at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported. Content Add-ins can have an initial size but are thereafter fully re-sizable by the user.

Since dynamically changing the size could dramatically impact a document's layout, it would likely confuse (if not outright infuriate) the content owner.

*Imagine discovering in the middle of a presentation that your thoughtfully constructed slide had been unexpectedly altered by a dynamically sized content control.* :)

Comment: I was hitting my head against the wall. Thanks. But! is there a way of adding dynamic content to a slide in read view. I can add dynamic content on the content add in but I am not able to add the content to the active read slide.